# Maximize window size instead of doing fullscreen mode on iTerm?

Tags: iterm2

I just did a factory reset on my Macbook. Before I did this reset, Command + Enter used to make my terminal session maximize in size, but it wouldn't do the "full screen presentation mode" thing. Now, Command + Enter goes into full screen mode. Is there any way to change it to what I had before?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I figured it out.

You have to go to your iTerm preferences and go to the "General" tab. Under the "Window" section, uncheck the option called **"Use Native Fullscreen windows"**

[image]

Comment: With "Lion-style" you can also Option-click the Maximize button/widget/gem.

Comment: Look for native fullscreen windows if you do not have Lion-style fullscreen windows

Comment: I'm using version 3.1.4 and it now appears to have changed to "Native fullscreen windows" in the same section.

Comment: Thank you this feature is very irritating when switching between apps.

Comment: the answer is a bit dated so I edited it, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/425106/83871

Answer (score 1):

It's possible,

You can assign a shortcut for the Zoom menu item from System Preferences:
[image]